# In AWS s3, how to allow read and write only in specific prefixes (using a wildcard)

Tags: amazon-s3, permissions

I have a bucket that has these prefixes:

- 1_user/
- 2_user/
- 10_user/

Users have access to all bucket by default, but I want to deny access to this specific bucket to all prefixes except those listed above (read/write), for which I tried something like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "BlockReadWriteListAccessExceptUser",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "BlockReadWriteAccess",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowReadWriteAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*_user"
        }
    ]
}
```

I realized that for get and put, I cannot use conditions, so how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bucket policy will not work because explicit deny **always** overrides the allows. I want to make this crystal clear. For example, say you want to add an object `999_user`. The object ARN is `arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/999_user`, which matches the deny statement with sid "BlockReadWriteAccess". S3 will deny this request right away without even looking at the "AllowReadWriteAccess" statement.

How to achieve the behaviour you want? The policy element [`NotResource`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_notresource.html) comes in handy in this case.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "BlockReadWriteListAccessExceptUser",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "BlockReadWriteAccess",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "NotResource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*_user*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. I cant believe I spent so much time looking for this but I never come across the NotResource thing. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**jellycsc**'s answer was super helpful to me, but it's not complete. You must also include an `Allow` statement for all resources in your bucket. Otherwise, you won't be able to access *any* resources.

You then follow that `Allow` statement with the `Deny` statement provided by **jellycsc**, which overrides the allow and denies all resources *except* the specific ones you'd still like to allow.

So the full policy should be the following:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadWriteAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "BlockReadWriteAccess",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "NotResource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*_user*"
        }
    ]
}
```